# Is it possible to query from google bug query using only a frontend?

Tags: authentication, google-bigquery, frontend

There is a public dataset database i would like to query but I don't want to host a robust backend only the frontend, a static page with javascript.

is it possible to provide a static page asset that dynamically loads from big query?

```html
<div>No data</div>
<button onclick="fetchBigQueryNoBackend()">Get Data</button>
```

Comment: You'd be making your bigquery account publicly accessible (endpoint and credentials stored in the static page). Don't do that!

Comment: I am exactly asking if it's possible to avoid

Comment: How will you identify users who are authorized to execute the query?  Given that Google has to charge for query processing if you were to publicly expose your Project as the billing entity for BigQuery, you DANGEROUSLY risk charges from malicious queries.  If your front end users authenticate AND they are authorized to query YOUR Project that is being charged for BigQuery queries ... then you should be able to call BigQuery APIs from the browser passing in your user's authenticated credentials.

Comment: @Kolban the database i want to query is public, i would like to make it accessible. could a user apply an api key at the frontend? as far as i know oauth requires a backend to use..

Comment: It's not the case that the "database" is public ... but rather the "data" is public.  When we think about BigQuery, Google charges two fees ... 1) The cost of storing data 2) The cost of processing queries.  For the public datasets, Google does not charge you for the storage, however, the query is not free.  Someone has to pay for the query against the data.  If YOU want YOUR users to query the public data, then YOU need to pay for the query charges.  YOU need to govern access to the requests to BigQuery.

Comment: @Kolban sure, do you know of a way i can allow users to setup their own billing and interface through the frontend?

Comment: Not really.  Google Cloud is (by and large) "Enterprise Software" and not consumer software.  You might want to consider updating the original post/question and provide a back-story on what it is you are looking to accomplish.  While there is a free tier to BigQuery, it is primarily meant for evaluators or constrained usage.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by @Kolban, Google Cloud is (by and large) "Enterprise Software" and not consumer software. When we think about BigQuery, Google charges the cost of storing data and the cost of processing queries. For the public datasets, Google does not charge you for the storage, however, the query is not free. Someone has to pay for the query against the data. If you want your users to query the public data, then you need to pay for the query charges.

You need to govern access to the requests to BigQuery. You cannot allow users to set up their own billing in GCP and interface through the frontend. While there is a free tier to BigQuery, it is primarily meant for evaluators or constrained usage.

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future. Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.